# Jenkins Pipeline - Maven compile failure

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Hello I keep running into this error when I try to compile the groovy script

```
stage('compile'){
    withMaven(maven: 'Maven_3.6.3') {
    sh 'mvn compile'
}
```

I have tried deleting the dir in my ubuntu ssh and still getting the error failed to copy, any ideas.

```
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to copy /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TeaCup-BE-Deck to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TeaCup-BE-Deck@tmp/withMavena4d15b3d/settings.xml
    at hudson.FilePath.copyTo(FilePath.java:2191)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.maven.WithMavenStepExecution2.setupSettingFile(WithMavenStepExecution2.java:759)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.maven.WithMavenStepExecution2.setupMaven(WithMavenStepExecution2.java:328)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.maven.WithMavenStepExecution2.doStart(WithMavenStepExecution2.java:208)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.maven.fix.jenkins49337.GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$run$0(GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: is it the full error log? Error is here : 

Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to copy /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TeaCup-BE-Deck to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TeaCup-BE-Deck@tmp/withMavena4d15b3d/settings.xml

Comment: hey saurabh14292 no the full error log is too long i just copied the cause of the error